# cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 3759

Tags: debian, cron

I had a cron job setup that I cleared using cron -r last night.

This morning I tried to enable it again and get this error each time:

cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 3759: Resource temporarily unavailable

I have tried rebooting and it didn't help. OS = Debian.

Comment: Please paste the output of these here: ls -alrth /var/run/crond.pid ls -alrth /var/

Answer (score 28):

I was making a dumb error. I should be using crontab command instead of cron.

Comment: Thanks. The same happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

> cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 5021: Resource temporarily unavailable

after removing pid from cron.pid file it started working, could you please check once if that helps