# cron job executing every minute but should be setup to execute every 4 hours

Tags: cron, scheduled-task

*Note: I've viewed [cron: can’t lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 3759](https://serverfault.com/questions/75580/cron-cant-lock-var-run-crond-pid-otherpid-may-be-3759) but I believe my question is different (but with the same resulting problem.)*

I'm very new to cron. I setup a script to run a python script every minute to test that everything was working. I did use `crontab` to accomplish this. It worked great, so I wanted to switch it to run every 4 hour.

I changed my `* * * * * {...}` to `* */4 * * * {...}` but the job is continues to run  every minute. It's been like this for the last hour or so.

When I attempt to run `cron restart` (thinking that would solve the problem), I receive the following error message:

> cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 2311: Resource temporarily unavailable

Is my cron syntax wrong? And why might I not be able to restart cron?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax should be

```
0 */4 * * * <command>
```

A `*` in the minute field causes it to run every minute, as you're experiencing. A zero will cause it to run at 0 minutes past the hour, every 4 hours.

Not sure why you can't restart cron; perhaps your cron job is DoS'ing your machine.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to fix my every-minute issue... Still getting the error when trying to restart but for now that doesn't matter. :-)  Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

Do you literally mean you typed "cron restart" to restart cron? You should probably be using the init script instead: /etc/init.d/cron restart. I suspect you're seeing the output of the cron server trying to start (i.e. ignoring the "restart" argument).